# Import unrelated repository to another repository branch

Tags: git, version-control

I have tried many answers on stackoverflow but none of them seem to work exactly how I want it. Basically I have a main repository that I have created a branch of (eg: 'feature') and I need to add another totally unrelated repository as a folder to this 'feature' branch. I need to have the history from the importing repository to merge as well. How would I go about doing this?

A little illustration:

```
"Project to import"
- "XXX folder"
- "YYY file"

"Main repository" - "feature-branch"
- "ABC folder"
- "Feature folder" - #How it should look after merging
-- "Imported files from other repo"
```

Comment: have you tried to add it as a submodule?

Comment: @clash I dont want to add it as a tracking repository. I just want to move the other project once in for all.

Comment: Alright. I had a similar problem some time ago and ended up in copying my changes by hand and writing down the history in this commit message. Maybe there is a better way, but sometimes it saves time to stop searching ;) Depends on the number of commits in the other repo of course...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are adding the merged repository to a new directory.

Try the following commands

```
git remote add unrelated <url-of-other-repo>
git fetch unrelated <branch-in-other-repo>
mkdir -p <path/to/new/code>
touch <path/to/new/code/>temp
git add <path/to/new/code/>temp
git commit -m 'Bring in new directory'
git merge --no-ff unrelated/<branch-in-other-repo> -s recursive -Xsubtree=<path/to/new/code>
git rm <path/to/new/code/temp>
git commit --amend --no-edit
git remote remove unrelated
```

(You need to add the temp file because Git does not track empty directories.)

This will give you a regular merge commit with all history from both sides.

Comment: This seemed to work but 
`git merge --no-ff unrelated/<branch-in-other-repo> -s recursive -Xsubtree=<path/to/new/code>`
Always copies code into parent directory and I couldnt move it to the feature folder

Comment: @user3312508 Did you create that directory (and a file in it) in your old main repository?

Comment: Yep I did. But then I used git mv to move the files and it worked. Thank you

Comment: Well. I tried it before I posted the answer, and it worked just fine for me. I guess it's fine for you, but if there were files/directories with the same names as you original repository, you would have had a problem. Do you mind posting a history of your commands with private information aliased?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution.

- Add **importing** repo as remote. `git remote add imported <url_to_imported>`.
- Fetch the branch that you need (**impbr** in this example). `git fetch imported impbr:impbr`.
- Switch to newly created local branch that is based on *imported* branch from **imported** repo. `git checkout -b impbr remotes/imported/impbr`.
- Now you can remove **importing** remote because it is not required for other steps. `git remote remove imported`.
- Fix directory structure in that branch as you like: create target folder "Feature", move everything ("XXX folder", "YYY file") to that folder, commit all those changes. New commit should contain only renames. `git mv . Feature/ && git add --all . && git commit -m 'Moved all files to "Feature" dir.'`
- Switch to **feature** branch and merge *fixed* branch **impbr** into it. `git checkout feature && git merge impbr`.
- Now you can safely remove **impbr** because it is not required anymore. `git branch -d impbr`.

Comment: How does this bring in the history of the other repository? The question clearly asks, "I need to have the history from the importing repository to merge as well."

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood what you were doing.