# Move a GIT repo as a branch of another

Tags: git, branch, rebase

How do I achieve the following? I have a new repo New_Repo which is the current repo we all are working on. I would like to create WhatINeed, but have repeatedly failed to do so.

I understand that the commit ID will change and we are fine with this.

```
Old_Repo ........................... (Master, which is also v1)
            |......... (ModA) 

New_Repo.(Empty Master)
        |............. (v2)

WHatINeed.(Empty Master)
         |........................... (v1)
         |       |......... (ModA)
         |............. (v2)
```

I have been able to get to add the Old_repo/master onto the WhatINeed master. But its not a branch like I want it.

I am already refering to [Insert a commit before the root commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645450/insert-a-commit-before-the-root-commit-in-git?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) But this gives me a flat structure without the ModA branch. Is there something wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First, define what you mean by *branch*. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25068543/what-exactly-do-we-mean-by-branch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import unrelated repository to another repository branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784385/import-unrelated-repository-to-another-repository-branch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to create a new branch (say, `oldRepoBranch`) into `WhatINeed` repo that will have the same commit history of `Old_Repo's master` branch.

Add a new remote (say, `oldRepo`) with the url of `Old_Repo` into `WhatINeed` repo.

```
// WhatINeed repo
$ git remote add oldRepo <Old_Repo url> 
$ git fetch oldRepo
```

Create a new branch `oldRepoBranch` with the history of `ldRepo/master`.

```
$ git checkout -b oldRepoBranch oldRepo/master
$ git log 
// oldRepoBranch commit history = Old_Repo/master commit history
```

Comment: Thanks @sajib-khan. Now I have two remotes. How do I get rid of the <Old_Repo url>  and just use the new one?

Comment: remote `origin` still exists that is the new repo actually. So, you can use remote `origin` for pull/push/etc. you can also delete the oldRepo remote but not mandatory (`$ git remote rm oldRepo`)